# SQL query with single quotes using spring jdbctemplate

Tags: java, prepared-statement, spring-jdbc

I was trying to use jdbctemplate to run a query against Postgres database and query has single quotes with dynamic values inside. Prepared statement is not able to replace ? with the value as it was inside single quotes. Please suggest if there any way to escape or have prepared statement replace those values.

```
select * from test where xpath('/a:name/a:first/text()=?', xml);
```

? in the above query should be replaced with some value like "testuser"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters are not recognized in string literals.

So move the parameter out of the string. And the compared value needs to be put into quotes.

```
select * from test where xpath('/a:name/a:first/text()=''' || ? || '''', xml);
```

Comment: That helped. Thank you!!